# Method Parameters C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I wrote a method like this in C#.

```
 MethodBase method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
 string key ="";
 for (int i = 0; i < method.GetParameters().Length; i++)
 {
     key=method.GetParameters().Name;
     // need value of parameter here             
 }
```

I'm getting parameter names through the above code. My question is: How can I get the values of the parameters which are coming to my method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't - not without using the debugger API, at least (which is distinctly non-trivial). That information isn't available via reflection. In particular, the `MethodBase` object you're fetching is probably going to be the same one on every invocation.

(I don't think the method you've written is *quite* as you've shown either, and I really *hope* you're not calling `GetParameters` inside a loop like that, but that's a side issue.)

Comment: First of all,thanks for your interesting.As you mentioned,How can I write by using the debugger API?

Comment: @Selo: It's not something I've used myself, but have a look at [pages like this](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4692/how-the-net-debugger-works/) - I don't know how much it's changed for .NET 4, either.